# Rails Building Objects with query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, function, methods

Why can't I do this?

```
  def current_event
    @current_event = Event.where(:start_date.lte => current_time, :end_date.gte => current_time).first

    @current_event.days_left = days_left_function
    return @current_event
  end
```

It returns a "No Method" error...which I get. I'm trying to call a method on this object? But how do I add to the object like in the rails create function??

**Edit**

I'm really sorry, but I've confused you because I'm so novice.

The `.days_left` is returning no method error...I just want to be able to call `@current_event.days_left` in my view.

So, I'm defining `@current_event` and I want to add `days_left` to that object.

Comment: Can you show us the full error? What method is resulting in the No Method exception?

Comment: @meagar Unless he's using a special query library such as Squeel, I think you are probably right.

Comment: @carlosramireziii Yes, possibly, in which case there should *really* be another tag here. This is not vanilla Rails syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why can't I do this?

<strike>Because you've invented a syntax that you want to use but which isn't founded on any form of reality? You can't just make up syntaxes and expect them to work.</strike>

Scratch that: Presumably you're using [Mongoid](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html#queries), which I'm unfamiliar with. If that's the case, the error is likely not because you're invoking `.lte` on a symbol, but because the `where` returned zero results and you're invoking `days_left` on `nil`.

In the case that you're not using Mongoid, my original answer stands:

To ask for records where a field is between two values, use the range operator:

```
Event.where(current_time: start_date..end_date)
```

To ask for records using less-than or greater-than or not equal, you need to build your own query, interpolating values into it with `?`:

```
Event.where('start_date <= ? and end_date >= ?', current_time, current_time).
```

Comment: Thanks...no need to be mean, though. I'm new to rails, so my invented syntax is just me trying to learn. `.lte` and `.gte` does work, though the range function is probably better rails...please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking to make sure that the result of your query is not nil. If `Event.where(...)` returns an empty association, then `.first` will return `nil`. If you try calling `.days_left` on `nil` then you will receive an error.

To guard against this, you should do a `nil` check. Something like the following

```
@current_event = Event.where(:start_date.lte => current_time, :end_date.gte => current_time).first
@current_event.days_left = days_left_function unless @current_event.nil?
```